# Can't detect the cause of infinite loop in a 'while loop' in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've got an infinite loop inside my while loop and I can't find the cause.

It's a simple function that returns the sum of the argument's digits. I use a while loop because it needs to add up the digits until it lands at a one digit number.
I made sure that I added a statement that would make sure that at a certain point the loop will break., But it obviously doesn't.

```
function digital_root(n) {
 num = n;
 sum = 0;
 while (num.toString().length>1){
      for (i=0; i<num.toString().length; i++) {
           sum += parseInt(num.toString()[i])    
       }
       num = sum;
  }
  return sum;
}
digital_root(456)
```

I get a warning that I have an infinity loop on line 4 (while loop).
I hoped that `num=sum`would reassign the new integer (with reduced number of digits) to the `num`variable and thus at some point break out of the loop. Is this wrong?

What further confuses me is that most of the JS editors I've used to debug the problem return an output, but it takes ages. So is it an infinite loop or is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the question I noticed that you're trying to reduce an integer down to a single number. The issue with your code was that `sum` was set to `0`, only before the *while* loop. Meaning that it didn't reset for the second, third, ... run.

Moving `sum = 0` into the while loop resolves this issue. I've also added variable declarations at the top to avoid setting global variables.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  var num, sum, i;

  num = n;
  while (num.toString().length > 1) {
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num.toString().length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(num.toString()[i]);
    }
    num = sum;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(digital_root(456));
```

Here written in a recursive manner, a style that I personally more prefer:

```js
function digital_root(integer) {
  // guard against things that might result in an infinit loop, like floats
  if (!Number.isInteger(integer) || integer < 0) return;
  
  const chars = integer.toString().split("");
  if (chars.length == 1) return integer;
  
  return digital_root(
    chars.map(char => parseInt(char))
         .reduce((sum, digit) => sum + digit)
  );
}

console.log(digital_root(456));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, [3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r)! I'm a bit mindblown by your second version of the code. I never thought that it was possible to return a function call within the same function instead of a while loop. Wow!

Comment: @EliFabrikant Thanks. When I first read the question I didn't notice the sentence *"I use a while loop because it needs to add up the digits until it lands at a one digit number."*, so I upped [the answer of Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303805/3982562). Only after my re-read did I notice that this wasn't the answer you're looking for. The question is formulated very well, but I guess that specific was surrounded by too much noise. I'm not quite sure how I would've formulated the question, maybe put the requirements in a list. Here on SO people often skip half of what's written.

Answer (score 4):

You have a nested loop structure where the first condition is always true.

For getting only a number below 10, you could call the function again as recursion.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
    var num = n.toString(), // declare and use the string value
        sum = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(num[i], 10)
    }
    return sum > 9
        ? digital_root(sum)
        : sum;
}

console.log(digital_root(456));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nina. but this hasn't solved my issue yet. The challenge here is that I need to keep adding up the digits of the sum as long as the sum>9. Or in other words, the function must return a single digit integer. This is the reason why I used a while loop in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got the answer, here is another way to meet the result

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  // convert the number to string
  // use split to create an array of number viz ['4','5','6']
  // use reduce to sum the number after converting to number
  // 0 is the initial value
  return n.toString().split('').reduce((a, c) => a + parseInt(c, 10), 0)
}
console.log(digital_root(456))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, brk, but just as I wrote Nina this hasn't solved my issue yet. The challenge here is that I need to keep adding up the digits of the sum as long as the sum>9. Or in other words, the function must return a single digit integer. This is the reason why I used a while loop in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding all the nested loops that lead to a situation such as that you're facing, I'd rather do it in a more readable way.

```
function digital_root(n) {
    sum = n;

    while(sum.toString().length > 1) {
        sum = sum.toString()
       .split('')
       .map(digit => parseInt(digit, 10))
       .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
    }

    return sum;
}

console.log(digital_root(456));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, aghashamim. But You've missed an important element of the problem: the function must return a single-digit integer. Hence the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I think I overlooked it, although you've already got the answer, I've just updated the code in my answer so that it fulfills what is required.